# how could I create a modal with a image in it and the link of the modal is the image itself (on a smaller version))

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I want to show some image in a thumbnail gallery in which if you click an image then it will appear larger in a modal.

If i keep the link of the modal as an image then it does not show anything at header or footer other than the close sign in top right corner.

I am using bootstrap. I also want to know if i could replace the `img` tag to `<a>` tag to open the modal section. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <img id="image-modal" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/Desert.jpg" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" alt="">
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/Desert.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <p>This is footer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [modal event listener](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) and pass the image to modal

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var img = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src'); // get image
        $('#showimg').attr('src' , img); //load image in modal
    });
});
```

add `id="showimg"` to image tag `<img>` in Modal Body

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="" id="showimg">
</div>
```

[Fiddle with `<img>` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/yLaak490/)

Yes you can also do it with `<a>` tag

`<a>` tag

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="imagepath" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Open Image</a>
```

and event listener script will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var img = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href'); // get image with <a> tag
        $('#showimg').attr('src' , img); //load image in modal
    });
});
```

[Fiddle with `<a>` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/yLaak490/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Bootstrap only, but this is what seems like it'd help for what you want to do:
https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/

I use it on a few websites of mine exactly for this case.

Answer (score 1):

try this [Bootstrap-Image-Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery) plugin will help you.
   check [Demo](https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/).